# Do custom error messages in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I'm new in Larvel 4.2 here! How do I do a custom error messages in Laravel 4.2? And where do I put these codes? I've been using the defaults and I kind of wanted to use my own.

Comment: Is this for custom error messages when you're using validation on a form?

Comment: yes i'm trying to use this when validating a form

Comment: The answer below is perfect for you then, simply place the code inside the controller function that the form uses and it will implement the custom error messages you define.

Comment: thanks i just don't know where to put it

Comment: I have added an answer to show you how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-error-messages

Did you use Google? Check the documentation (official) it has everything. Be less lazy.

```
$messages = array(
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
);

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: im sorry if i sounded lazy and stupid. 
thanks i just don't know where to put it

Comment: I didn't say you're stupid. Doing something on your own at first is the best teacher. Then ask... Enjoy Laravel - it's really good piece of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer given by slick, here is how you could use it in a real example of a store function inside a controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {    
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'id1' => 'required|between:60,512',
            'id2' => 'required|between:60,512',
            'id3' => 'required|unique:table',
        ], [
            'id1.required' => 'The first field is empty!',
            'id2.required' => 'The second field is empty!',
            'id3.required' => 'The third field is empty!',
            'id1.between' => 'The first field must be between :min - :max characters long.',
            'id2.between' => 'The second answer must be between :min - :max characters long.',
            'id3.unique' => 'The third field must be unique in the table.',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }

        //... Do something like store the data entered in to the form
}
```

Where the `id` should be the ID of the field in the form you want to validate.

You can check out all the rules you can use [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#available-validation-rules).